# Restoring with Deja Dup program

Tags: 12.04, backup, deja-dup

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 and I've been using the default Deja Dup program for weekly backups, which I store in a separate disk.

**My question is this:** If I wanted to perform a restore using this program, would I just select the folder containing all of the difftar.gz files and it will restore all of my data?

A hypothetical situation would be if I were to install ubuntu on a new computer, would I be able to bring my data up from the folder created by the backup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that’s correct when restoring backups you can chose where and which folder or files you will restore. You can restore backup as whole or part of it.

When restoring you can restore to any place you point Déjà Dup. 
So, yes you would be able to bring your data up from the folder created by the backup

Comment: Even on a separate computer? I mean to say, performing the backup on Computer A, and restoring the data onto Computer B. Pardon, I'm fairly new.

Comment: yes even on separate computer. You can restore to external HDD too for example.